# How do i list my ICO token created on Stellar to an exchange?

Tags: trading, stellar

I believe stellar has a built in exchange called stellarterm for tokens created through their platform. My question is am I able to list my token on another exchanges or are we limited to only stellarterm?

Comment: check this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7lQ801k6RX4

Answer (score 1):

Most exchanges will only list coins which have a proven record of exchange volume and price. If you create your own token it is unlikely it will be used by anyone else, or purchased on an exchange, so it is thus unlikely any exchange will want to list it I'm afraid.